# git: fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD' with all new repos

Tags: git

The issue was a heavy amount of shell customization.

If I try to create a new repo with `git init` it gives me `fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'` twice.

If I do `git log` it gives me the same error three times.

I have deleted `~/.git` , `~/.config` , and `~/.gitconfig` based on other answers I've found stating I might have created the repo in my home directory. The only repo that doesn't give me this issue is the one I cloned from someone else.

I'm unsure what I did besides deleting anything in my home directory with git info in it.

As per request:

```
jsw:~ jsw$ mkdir test
jsw:~ jsw$ cd test
jsw:test jsw$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/jsw/test/.git/
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
jsw:test(master|23448707m) jsw$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'


jsw:~ jsw$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Comment: Check whether one of the parent directory of your project's root directory contains a `.git` folder. If that's not the case, do this: right after `git init` (in a new directory not already initialised for Git), inspect the contents of the HEAD file by running `cat .git/HEAD` and report here.

Comment: It did have a .git directory in the parent directory but I deleted before making the new directory and running `git init` . Updated my question

Comment: What happens if you run `git status` from your home directory?

Comment: `jsw:~ jsw$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: Have you made an initial commit?

Comment: `cat` is telling you that you have a bad default revision.  Tell me about your shell.  Are you trying to do something silly with your prompt like print the current branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ran `cat .git/HEAD` and it replied:

```
ref: refs/heads/master
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
```

Since `cat` is not a `git` command and doesn't care about your `HEAD`, I suspect that you have configured your shell to do something like print the name of the current branch.

In fact, looking at your shell prompt:

```
jsw:test(master|23448707m) jsw$
```

I'm certain of it.

Either turn off whatever shell magic you are trying to perform, fix it so that it knows how to deal with new repositories, or simply cope with the error messages until you've made your first commit.

Comment: Thank you. I'll figure out how to fix my shell. It wasn't until I was pointed towards `--allow-empty` that the message went away. When I killed my shell and started fresh I no longer got the error.

Answer (score 6):

You maybe getting this error because you don't have any commits on your HEAD revision, so when you make a `git log` it won't find any commit on the HEAD.

Please try:

```
mkdir test
cd test
git init
git commit -m 'Initial Commit' --allow-empty
git log
```

Comment: This is the right reason for me. A simple fact that I just know.

Answer (score 0):

please use the below command

git init
git commit -m 'initial commit' --allow-empty
git log

Then you run the reflog you will see ref#